# How to open a dialogue from an Ribbon button in Outlook web addin?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-web-app

I am trying to open a dialogue from the ribbon button.

I have added a ribbon button Engagement to the MessageComposeCommandSurface which will execute a function in function-file to open a dialogue

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>d52ea32e-267b-422c-85be-72fabbf1f5c9</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>APP</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Appliaction " />
  <Description DefaultValue="Application Description"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/assets/icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://support.contoso.com" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44340</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id ="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPane">
                  <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>openEngagementDiag</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>


          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/assets/app-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/assets/app-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/assets/app-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/Function-File/function-file.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/Home/ReadPane"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44340/Home/Compose"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Sample Label"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="Application"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Engagement"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Map to Engagement"/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Map to Engagement"/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Engagement"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying current engagement"/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying current engagement"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Following is the function file defined.

```
declare var Office;

(() => {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = () => {
      console.log("Hello World")
  };

function openEngagementDiag(){
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    'https://localhost:4200/#/MessageCompose', 
    {height: 30, width: 20},
    function(asyncResult){
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        let errorMessage = null;

        switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
        case 12004:
            errorMessage = 'Domain is not trusted';
            break;
        case 12005:
            errorMessage = 'HTTPS is required';
            break;
        case 12007:
            errorMessage = 'A dialog is already opened.';
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = asyncResult.error.message;
            break;
        }        
    }
    else {       
    }
    });
}
})();
```

The ribbon button is being displayed and when it is clicked , an info bar appears as shown below stating "TestApp is working on the request", indicating that something is happening behind the scenes

[image]

What I am doing wrong here?

EDIT : My Outlook Web add-in project is SPA using angular v6.x

Comment: Is the dialog not opening or the dialog is opening but you still see the progress infobar?

Comment: The dialog is not opening and all I see is the progress infobar

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT could you give me some hints?

Comment: There are few things you can do to debug this:
1. Check that the url you provided is accessible in your default browser
2. Since you are loading local host, you could be running into a cross zone issue. Check your console errors.
3. You did not specify to load the url inside an iframe, try passing parameter displayInIframe:true
4. Are you able to hit the breakpoint inside your function? You can try running the same code in a taskpane control to make sure it works.
5. Ensure that the url you are trying to open is specified in the AppDomains section of the manifest.

Comment: 1. I have verified that the url is accessible in default browser
3. Even after specifying to load url in iframe, the issue exists.
5. The same code works from taskpane.
6. Url is mentioned in the app domain

Comment: When i use the template provided by Visual Studio for Outlook add-in , the dialog will open. Here I am serving the pages using ASP.NET Core MVC Application (which shouldnt be problem,should it?). 
Is there a way by which i can debug without using Visual Studio?

Comment: That is not a problem. You can use browser debugging tools. Does this issue impact both OWA and Outlook or only OWA?

Comment: Currently issue exists in outlook client.

Comment: It looks like you are currently using arrow function (=>) in your code which is not supported by IE (which is what Desktop Outlook currently runs add-ins in)

Comment: I have tried to replicate issue in OWA  and made some observations . 
1. Function file is loading and the Office is initializing.
2. I put couple of console.log inside the 'openEngagementDiag' function (which is the one to be triggered) . No log is appearing in console.
Which means function cannot be called.
a.) The function names are same in manifest and function-file.
b) I have changed all arrow functions

Comment: I understood the root cause. The functions are expected to be in window object. my functions were inside a IIFE . Bringing the functions from inside the IIFE solved the problem. Thanks @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT team

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not do it for you, but based on a recent experience I've had with a Word add-in, chances are great. Add an `event` parameter to your handler function and be sure to signal the event's completion by calling its `completed` method.

```
function openEngagementDiag(event) {
    // ...
    event.completed();
}
```

I hope this helps.